# WordPress - Uploads stuck at 'crunching' for subscriber

Tags: wordpress

I've configured WordPress to allow subscribers to upload via the Media area on the backend by giving them the 'upload_files' capability. However, when I try to start an upload as a subscriber (in WP 3.3), the upload freezes at the 'crunching' step. When I check the Library, the file has been added to the site, but the 'crunching' step never proceeds to the image details screen...

Any thoughts on what's wrong? It doesn't seem like a file permissions or a PHP memory issue to me. This is kind of important for the network I'm working on.

Note that everything work perfectly as an administrator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this answered in the WordPress trac. For Google bait: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19817

> That would be because you've given the subscriber permission to upload_files, but not to edit_posts, so that after it's uploaded they are not allowed to change any of the data associated with it (title, caption, description etc).

Related request for more robust attachment capabilities in WP: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19834

Answer (score 0):

> Add This code in functions.php file

```
function add_media_cap()
{   
  global $current_user;
  $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
  $user_roles_id = $current_user->ID;
  $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
  if($user_role =='subscriber')
   {
        $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
        $subscriber->add_cap('upload_files');

   }
 }
 add_action('init', 'add_media_cap');
```